# Jquery closest find issue - this.closest(...).find is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Why my `(this).closest('.row').find('.col-lg-10').remove();` doesn't work and sending me errors in log?

```
<div class="row section-first">
    <div class="col-lg-2 text-center text-grayer my-auto p-2">
        <p class="h6">Newbie</p>
        <p class="h5">
            <i class="fa fa-diamond m-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-diamond m-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </p>
        <a href="http://localhost/forum/uzytkownik/krystian2160"><img class="mb-1 border-gray" src="http://localhost/forum/public/storage/avatars/1598320e3908c6.jpg" style="width: 112px; height: 112px;"/></a>
        <p class="small m-0">Cirapuszka</p>
        <!-----------------------------------------------------------------------------Reputacja----------->

        <p class="m-0"><span class="badge bg-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> 0</span></p>
        <p class="m-0"><span class="badge bg-inverse"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> 0</span></p>
        <p class="text-muted">3 postów</p>

        <!------------------------------------------------------------------------Button do edycji posta--->

        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm pointer post-edit">Edytuj Post</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10 text-gray p-2">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="offset-lg-2 small col-lg-9">
    </div>
```

This is my HTML
And I have here this button

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm pointer post-edit">
                        Edytuj Post
                    </button>
```

It it scripted in jquery like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.post-edit', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    (this).closest('.row').find('.col-lg-10').remove();
                });

Uncaught TypeError: this.closest(...).find is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (voluptas-eum-voluptatem-soluta-numquam-ipsum-totam-est:293)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery.js:3)
```

It works when it is like `(this).closest('.row').remove();` It deletes whole row, but it's not what I intend to do.

`col-lg-10` containing content in this post have to be deleted.

So I try using `(this).closest('.row').find('.col-lg-10').remove();` but as I said this doesn't work and I don't know why, because we go first to `.row` by traversing UP in DOM by `closest` and then down by `find` to `col-lg-10`

What is wrong here?

Comment: change it to `$(this).closest('.row').find('.col-lg-10').remove();`

Comment: hah, haha. that .closest isn't jQuery, it's the one that [browsers now provide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest). you've forgotten a `$` at the start of that line. dom nodes don't have a .find method. They do however have a [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) method.

Comment: `(this).closest('.row').find('.col-lg-10').remove();` need to be `$(this).closest('.row').find('.col-lg-10').remove();`.Seems like TYPO mistake

Comment: If there's only one `col-lg-10` element to remove, you can do it without jQuery like this:  `this.closest('.row').querySelector('.col-lg-10').remove()`

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the question comments, you're missing the jQuery identifier.

Change this:

```
(this).closest('.row').find('.col-lg-10').remove();
```

To this:

```
$(this).closest('.row').find('.col-lg-10').remove();
```